# scan/take picture of check and populate data

Tags: iphone, camera, cordova

Hey, can i scan/take picture of a check and identify the account number and routing number using phonegap on iPhone

Comment: @Neha.. did you get solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, at least not directly.

You are going to need to look into some opensource ocr software and integrate it into phone gap.

Comment: Do we have pointers to any open source to do that. I am unable to find.

Comment: @Neha - I'd recommend reading the question [Is there any open source OCR project for the iPhone out there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964181/is-there-any-open-source-ocr-project-for-the-iphone-out-there).